# How can I conclude $R=1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

$a_n$ be a sequence of complex number such that $\sum |a_n| <\infty$, $\sum n|a_n|=\infty$, Then I need to find the Radius of Convergence of $\sum a_nz^n$

$\lim |a_n|=0$ from the first condition so $0<|a_n|<\epsilon$ so $0^{1\over n}<|a_n|^{1\over n}<\epsilon^{1\over n}$

Now $R={1\over \limsup|a_n|^{1\over n}}$

How can I conclude $R=1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know from $\sum|a_n|<\infty$ that the series converges for $z=1$, so that $R\ge1$. Now let $r>1$. Then $r^n\ge n$ for $n$ large enough. Since $\sum n|a_n|=\infty$, $\sum |a_n|r^n=\infty$. The power series diverges for all $z$ with $|z|=r$, so that $R\le r$. Since $r$ cam be taken as close to $1$ as we want, it follows that $R\le1$.